# WatchKit Long Look Notification not showing up

Tags: ios, watchkit

I set up a dynamic long look interface.  I'm running the app on a watch with an iBeacon.

When the beacon comes in range I receive the static notification on the watch but when I keep looking the long look does not show up.

I set breakpoints on the first line inside `didReceiveLocalNotification` and on the first line of `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.  It doesn't break because it's never getting called.

Any thoughts on where to begin looking for why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.

1) When you click "has a dynamic interface" in the static notification, Xcode creates a notification category called "myCategory".  I hadn't set my notification category to match that.

2) I removed "myCategory" and left it at "default" thinking that this would work because it was the only dynamic notification.  No dice.

3) I set the category of my notification and matched in the notification category and now it works fine.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: awesome.. it helped.